# Getting an iOS Share/Action Extension to show up only for a single image

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I have an action extension in an iOS app that I only want to be available when the user is sharing a single image. The `NSExtension` key in my `info.plist` looks like this.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImagesWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```

The only activation rule I am using is `NSExtensionActivationSupportsImagesWithMaxCount` with a value of `1`. However, the extension still shows up when sharing other things. For example, it shows up when I hit the action button in Safari.

In the Safari case, there is no image to be pulled out of the `NSExtensionContext`.

Anyone have any idea how to get my extension to *not* show up in those cases?

Comment: Looks like a predicate could fix it: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549427/action-extension-activation-rule-predicate-doesnt-hide-the-action-when-multiple

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654593/how-do-i-set-nsextensionactivationrule-predicates

Comment: Sorry for the 3 individual comments, but i feel like it's easier to read when separate. Those are 3 distinct links.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. It is strange that what I had did not work, but this solution was simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to answer it or should i so i claim the bounty? Haha

Comment: I put an answer there, but if you put one down I'll give you the bounty!

Comment: Thanks so much, I really need need the rep boost and I dont want your bounty to go waste!

Comment: I think you have to manually award me the bounty on top of accepting my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a predicate could fix it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

[Action Extension activation rule predicate doesn't hide the action when multiple of the same type is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549427/action-extension-activation-rule-predicate-doesnt-hide-the-action-when-multiple)

[How do I set NSExtensionActivationRule predicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654593/how-do-i-set-nsextensionactivationrule-predicates)

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get this working thanks to @Matthew-Bordas. The solution was to use a predicate.

```html
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>SUBQUERY ( extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY ( $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;public.image&quot; ).@count == 1 ).@count == 1</string>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
  <string>MainInterface</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```